# Flutter pubspec dependencies from git (Flutterfire)

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies

How can I set my pubspec to use FlutterFire dependencies from a forked repository?

```yaml
firebase_storage:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/marcuslindemannrohden/flutterfire
firebase_core:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/marcuslindemannrohden/flutterfire
firebase_auth:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/marcuslindemannrohden/flutterfire
cloud_firestore:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/marcuslindemannrohden/flutterfire
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the path to the package.

```yaml
firebase_storage:
  git:
    url: https://github.com/marcuslindemannrohden/flutterfire.git
    path: packages/firebase_storage/firebase_storage

firebase_auth:
  git:
    url: https://github.com/marcuslindemannrohden/flutterfire.git
    path: packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth

cloud_firestore:
  git:
    url: https://github.com/marcuslindemannrohden/flutterfire.git
    path: packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore
```